# How to use Vector2 and Vector3 in place of deprecated UV and Vertex?

Tags: three.js

I am creating a custom geometry and came across this error:
THREE.Vertex has been DEPRECATED. Use THREE.Vector3 instead. 
THREE.UV has been DEPRECATED. Use THREE.Vector2 instead.

I'm not sure how to proceed with my code below. How would I make this update? Thank you.

```
Saturn_RingFunct = function ( innerRadius, outerRadius, nSegments ) {
//var ringsmap = "./images/SatRing.png";
//var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(ringsmap);
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( 
 { color:"yellow",wireframe:true/*map:       texture, transparent:true, ambient:0xffffff*/ } );
//var ringsMesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

var Saturn_Rings = new THREE.Geometry();

 //THREE.Geometry.call( this );

var outerRadius = outerRadius || 1,
    innerRadius = innerRadius || .5,
    gridY = nSegments || 10;

var i, twopi = 2 * Math.PI;
var iVer = Math.max( 2, gridY );

var origin = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
//this.vertices.push(new THREE.Vertex(origin));

for ( i = 0; i < ( iVer + 1 ) ; i++ ) {

var fRad1 = i / iVer;
var fRad2 = (i + 1) / iVer;
var fX1 = innerRadius * Math.cos( fRad1 * twopi );
var fY1 = innerRadius * Math.sin( fRad1 * twopi );
var fX2 = outerRadius * Math.cos( fRad1 * twopi );
var fY2 = outerRadius * Math.sin( fRad1 * twopi );
var fX4 = innerRadius * Math.cos( fRad2 * twopi );
var fY4 = innerRadius * Math.sin( fRad2 * twopi );
var fX3 = outerRadius * Math.cos( fRad2 * twopi );
var fY3 = outerRadius * Math.sin( fRad2 * twopi );

var v1 = new THREE.Vector3( fX1, fY1, 0 );
var v2 = new THREE.Vector3( fX2, fY2, 0 );
var v3 = new THREE.Vector3( fX3, fY3, 0 );
var v4 = new THREE.Vector3( fX4, fY4, 0 );
Saturn_Rings.vertices.push( new THREE.Vertex( v1 ) );
Saturn_Rings.vertices.push( new THREE.Vertex( v2 ) );
Saturn_Rings.vertices.push( new THREE.Vertex( v3 ) );
Saturn_Rings.vertices.push( new THREE.Vertex( v4 ) );

}

for ( i = 0; i < iVer ; i++ ) {

Saturn_Rings.faces.push(new THREE.Face3( i * 4, i * 4 + 1, i * 4 + 2));
Saturn_Rings.faces.push(new THREE.Face3( i * 4, i * 4 + 2, i * 4 + 3));
Saturn_Rings.faceVertexUvs[ 0 ].push( [
    new THREE.UV(0, 1),
    new THREE.UV(1, 1),
    new THREE.UV(1, 0) ] );
Saturn_Rings.faceVertexUvs[ 0 ].push( [
    new THREE.UV(0, 1),
    new THREE.UV(1, 0),
    new THREE.UV(0, 0) ] );
}

Saturn_Rings.computeCentroids();
Saturn_Rings.computeFaceNormals();
Saturn_Rings.computeVertexNormals();
//Saturn_Rings.boundingSphere = { radius: outerRadius };
var object = new THREE.Mesh(Saturn_Rings, material);
object.doubleSided = true;
object.doubleSided = true;
object.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
scene.add(object);
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

It means you can now use Vector3 and Vector2 objects directly where you previously needed to use Vertex and UV.

Instead of:

```
Saturn_Rings.faceVertexUvs[ 0 ].push( [
    new THREE.UV(0, 1),
    new THREE.UV(1, 1),
   new THREE.UV(1, 0) ] );
```

You can do:

```
Saturn_Rings.faceVertexUvs[ 0 ].push( [
    new THREE.Vector2(0, 1),
    new THREE.Vector2(1, 1),
   new THREE.Vector2(1, 0) ] );
```

And istead of:

```
var v1 = new THREE.Vector3( fX1, fY1, 0 );
Saturn_Rings.vertices.push( new THREE.Vertex( v1 ) );
```

You can do:

```
var v1 = new THREE.Vector3( fX1, fY1, 0 );
Saturn_Rings.vertices.push(v1);
```

And so on.